# Mapping API info to React Component

Tags: reactjs, mapping, lodash, github-api

I'm trying to create a Github search for user repos and display them in cards.  My ListComponent looks good when displayed, but I'm having trouble mapping the repo info to each card.  When I console.log the data it shows up as expected, but will not map to the cards.  I'm using fetch for the api calls and lodash for mapping.  Any help would be appreciated!

GithubSearch:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from  'react';
import ListComponent from './ListComponent';
import _ from 'lodash';

class GithubSearch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            repos: [],
            apiMsg:'',
            userInfo: {}
        }
    };

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ username: e.target.value });
        setTimeout(this.handleSubmit, 1000)
    }

    handleSubmit = () => {
        fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.username}/repos`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            this.setState({
                repos: [],
                apiMsg: err.message
            })
        })
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className='header'>Github Search</div>
                <form className='search'>
                    <input 
                        placeholder='Github user'
                        name='github user' 
                        type='text' 
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        value={this.state.username}
                    />
                    <button type='submit' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>Search</button>
                </form>
                <p>{this.state.apiMsg}</p>

                
                        <div className='right-container'>
                            {_.map(this.state.repos, repo => <ListComponent key={repo.id} {...repo}/>)}
                        </div>


            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default GithubSearch;
```

ListComponent:

```
import React from 'react'
import '../App.css'

const ListComponent = ({ name, description, language, html_url }) => {
    return (
        <div className='card'>
            <div className='card-body'>
                <h2><a href={html_url} target='_blank' rel="noreferrer">{name}</a></h2>
            </div>
            <div className='card-body'>
                <p>{description}</p>
            </div>
            <div className='card-body'>
                <p>Languages: {language}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ListComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to set state for repo after API response , you try below code

```
 handleSubmit = () => {
        fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.username}/repos`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)

            this.setState({repo:data})
        })
        .catch(err => {
            this.setState({
                repos: [],
                apiMsg: err.message
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: That’s still isn’t working. I think something is wrong with how I set up the information to be mapped to the list component. I’m still seeing the correct info log to the console.

Comment: Can you please console.log the this.state.repo in GithubSearch commponent and name, description, language, html_url in ListComponent?

Comment: Console.log of this.state.repo returned an array of all the user github repos as expected.  I don't know how to get a console.log of name, description, language, or html_url if the ListComponent is not rendering at all.

Comment: Instead of using lodash map can you try this one 
<div className='right-container'>
  {this.state.repos.map(repo=><ListComponent key={repo.id} {...repo}/>)  }
</div>

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not rendering anything for the ListComponent after switching from lodash.